# Change toolbar menu item action dynamically

Tags: android, button, menu, toolbar, menuitem

I've got this menu item on my toolbar, it's action `R.id.action_edit` sets all of my activity's edittext's status to enabled, I'm wondering how can I do to make that, when clicked, this button changes his action to the second action in the same menu.xml file, `R.id.action_save`, which updates the fields values into the database, so when clicked again, it would save the data.

Or if there is a way to set the first menuItem visibility to false and the second menuItem to visible when the first one is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to declare two global menu item (used in toolbar say id mEdit,mSave)

> MenuItem mEdit,mSave; EditText editText;

2. Give memory in

   ```
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
       mEdit= menu.findItem(R.id.mEdit);  
       mSave = menu.findItem(R.id.mSave);  
       hideMenuItem(); 
       return true;
       }
   ```
3. Define method

> ```
> private void hideMenuItem()
>  {
>     if(editText.getText().length()>0)
>         {
>           mEdit.setVisible(false);
>           mSave.setVisible(true);
>          }
>      else
>          {
>           mEdit.setVisible(true);
>           mSave.setVisible(false);
>           }
>  }
> ```

3. Add TextWatcher to editText in onTextChanged write this code (

   editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()

> ```
> public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
>     {
>       hideMenuItem();
>     }});
> ```